# Running phantomjs on linux using python

Tags: python, linux, phantomjs

I followed [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8778513/how-can-i-setup-run-phantomjs-on-ubuntu) and now when I type `phan` and then tab (`\t`) it does autocomplete to phantomJS.

Yet if I run `phantomJS -v` or `phantomJS --version` I get:

```
bash: /usr/local/bin/phantomjs: /lib/ld-linux.so.2: bad ELF interpreter: No such file or directory
```

Additionally if I try to run:

```
>>> from selenium import webdriver
>>> driver = webdriver.PhantomJS()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/phantomjs/webdriver.py", line 50, in __init__
    service_args=service_args, log_path=service_log_path)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/phantomjs/service.py", line 50, in __init__
    service.Service.__init__(self, executable_path, port=port, log_file=open(log_path, 'w'))
IOError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: 'ghostdriver.log'
>>>
```

If I try to follow [this I get](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17048594/how-to-disable-or-change-the-path-of-ghostdriver-log):

```
>>> import os
>>> driver = webdriver.PhantomJS(service_log_path=os.path.devnull)
Exception AttributeError: "'Service' object has no attribute 'log_file'" in <bound method Service.__del__ of <selenium.webdriver.phantomjs.service.Service object at 0x7f182ec13690>> ignored
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/phantomjs/webdriver.py", line 51, in __init__
    self.service.start()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/common/service.py", line 69, in start
    os.path.basename(self.path), self.start_error_message)
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: 'phantomjs' executable needs to be in PATH. 

>>>
```

Is my selenium/phatnomjs installed with the proper rights?

I created a directory `/home/ec2-user/temp` and set:

```
chmod 777 /home/ec2-user/temp
```

Yet

```
>>> from selenium import webdriver
>>> driver = webdriver.PhantomJS(service_log_path='/home/ec2-user/temp/ghostdriver.log')
```

Yields:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/phantomjs/webdriver.py", line 51, in __init__
    self.service.start()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/common/service.py", line 69, in start
    os.path.basename(self.path), self.start_error_message)
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: 'phantomjs' executable needs to be in PATH.
```

If I type `which phantomjs` I get:

```
$ which phantomjs
/usr/local/bin/phantomjs
```

Comment: Are you really sure about the capitalization? It's usually `phantomjs` and not `phantomJS`. Type `which phantomjs` to see where it is installed.

Comment: @ArtjomB. I updated the question.

Comment: Did you install PhantomJS through npm? Check if it is a symbolic link or sh wrapper around the actual executable

Comment: No I did what is in the answer to my top link above. It is a symbolic link to another path.

Comment: You mean you [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14267295/1816580)? If so, then this cannot be done for an RPi, because RPi doesn't have an x86 architecture. You would need to use an executable compiled for arm-hf, which [it](https://bitbucket.org/ariya/phantomjs/downloads) doesn't provide. You need to find another method of installing PhantomJS with the proper architecture.

Comment: Would npm do this properly?

Comment: No idea if there are appropriate executables for RPi in "phantomjs" or "phantomjs-prebuilt".

Comment: I will try and post my progress.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It very much sounds like a 64 vs 32 bits issue.

To find out whats the version of your ubuntu, you can run

```
$ uname -i
x86_64
```

Then make sure to [download](http://phantomjs.org/download.html) the correct version of phantom

- 32 bits version: https://bitbucket.org/ariya/phantomjs/downloads/phantomjs-2.1.1-linux-i686.tar.bz2
- 64 bits version: https://bitbucket.org/ariya/phantomjs/downloads/phantomjs-2.1.1-linux-x86_64.tar.bz2

Also make sure your lib are corresponding to the version of your OS.

Answer (score 0):

You can check out this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49729024/5957834).

```
driver = webdriver.PhantomJS(executable_path='Complete path/to/phantomjs.exe')
```

It worked well for me.